# docker-compose yaml.parser.ParserError

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With the following docker-compose.yml I always get a syntax error I can't explain (I don't see the difference in lines 2 and 3 between the two docker-compose.ymls)

```
---
version: '2'
  services:
    app-module:
      container_name: app-module:
      env_file: ./app-module:.env
      image: registry.x/app/app-module:latest
      network_mode: "bridge"
        ports:
        - "30303:30303"
      volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: node-volume
        target: /datadir
      - ./data:/data
      - ./log:/log
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 3
```

I don't see any syntax differences to other working files.

That's the working docker-compose.yml I used as the inspiration of my file:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  app-node:
    container_name: app-node
    env_file: ./app-node.env
    image: registry.x/group/app-node:latest
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "7990:7990"
      - "7999:7999"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./log:/log
```

Proof:

```
$ docker-compose config
services:
  app-node:
    container_name: app-node
    environment: {}
    image: registry.x/group/app-node:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
    - 7990:7990/tcp
    - 7999:7999/tcp
    volumes:
    - ...app-node/Test/data:/data:rw
    - ...app-node/Test/log:/log:rw
version: '2.0'
```

Answer (score 8):

Spaces matter in YAML. You have two spaces before `services:` that are not supposed to be there. You're telling YAML that `services` is in `version` but `version` already has a value.

It's the difference between:

```
foo: bar
  in_foo: bar
```

which will not work because `in_foo` is in `foo`, and:

```
foo: bar
not_in_foo: bar
```

that will work because `not_in_bar` is not in `foo`.

Alternatively, this would be valid syntax (but then docker-compose will fail because it expects a string in `version`):

```
version:
  services:
    foo: bar
```

Comment: I noticed there has been indention changes by copy&pasting the block from one file to another.

Fixing the indention on line 9 also made the errror message about line disappear.